# Probability and combinatorics Proof

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am trying to prove the following:

Let us consider 6 balls, 2 reds, 2 yellow and 2 blue. 
I want to compute the probability of chosen 2 balls either blue or red (BB, RR, BR, RB). I can see two ways. 
First, as I don't care if the balls are either red or blue, I see them as one group with four balls. $P_1= \frac{\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{6}{2}}$

Second, I can compute the individual probabilities and then add all of them P(BB)+P(BR)+P(RB)+P(RR). 
\begin{equation}
P_2= \frac{\binom{2}{2}}{\binom{6}{2}} +\frac{\binom{2}{1}}{\binom{6}{1}} \cdot  \frac{\binom{2}{1}}{\binom{5}{1}}+\frac{\binom{2}{1}}{\binom{6}{1}} \cdot  \frac{\binom{2}{1}}{\binom{5}{1}}+\frac{\binom{2}{2}}{\binom{6}{2}} 
\end{equation}

Is $P_1$ correct? If so, I want to prove that $P_1=P_2$ in a general case, i.e., we have $n$ balls where there are $n_1$ balls are of type one and $n_2$ balls of type 2 and $n_3$ balls of type 3 and we want to know the probability of chosen $r$ balls, where $r$ can be composed of either balls of type one or type two.

Edited: I am searching for an algebraic proof. (Thanks @joriki for pointing it out).

Comment: $P_1$ is correct, but $P_2$ has some errors.  The denominator of the first term should be $\binom 62$, yes?  And the second term is wrong as well.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I didn't notice the errors while typing.

Comment: Can you say something about what you mean by "proving" this? The fact that they're two counts of the same thing already proves that they're the same.

Comment: Yes, but they are not the same thing. They are red balls and blue balls. Normally, we should use P2. So I want to know if there is a formal proof to say that P1 is equivalent to P2, i.e., considering red balls and blue ones as same thing.

Comment: The only criterion for this problem is that you have yellow and non-yellow balls. For the non-yellow, it makes no difference if they are all the colors of the rainbow or just one color. Everything else boils down to slightly different methods of calculating the same thing, much like $3\cdot 4 = 3+3+3+3 = 4+4+4 = 12$

Comment: @Gabb: I'm not sure what you find insufficiently formal about the proof using the fact that they're two counts of the same thing. I get the impression that perhaps what you're interested in is an **algebraic** proof.

Comment: Thanks @joriki. I'm searching for an algebraic proof. I didn't know how to explain it.